# unable to run make during installation of kernel 3.3.6

Tags: kernel, compiling, qt, synaptic, qt-creator

```
desktop:~/Desktop/linux-3.3.6$ make xconfig
make[1]: Warning: File `scripts/kconfig/.zconf.tab.o.cmd' has modification time 1.7e+04 s in the future
  CHECK   qt
* Unable to find the QT4 tool qmake. Trying to use QT3
*
* Unable to find any QT installation. Please make sure that
* the QT4 or QT3 development package is correctly installed and
* either qmake can be found or install pkg-config or set
* the QTDIR environment variable to the correct location.
*
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `scripts/kconfig/.tmp_qtcheck', needed by `scripts/kconfig/qconf.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
```

when I tried to install `qt4-qmake` through synaptic manager ;
an error is displayed saying that `tz_data not found`.

Comment: First check what pkg;s are available with "sudo apt-cache search qmake". Check if you have the correct ppa in place for installing the dependencies. Alternatively work around would be to use "make menuconfig"

Answer (score 3):

Real simple solution:

apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev

It will also install a number of other files. Just say Y. Happy kernel compiling!